# Count occurrences in dataframe with two conditions without for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using the "diamonds" dataset from the ggplot2 package. I want to be able to count the number of diamonds which fulfill two conditions in the first n observations, in this case color 'E' and clarity 'SI2'. I have written the function below which solves this problem, however I would like to be able to do this without needing to run a for loop. Is there a way to keep this function working without the for loop? The dataset has 54000 obs.

```
library('ggplot2')
data(diamonds)

countfreq <- function(n) {
  #Set k to 0
  k <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    if (diamonds$color[i] == 'E' & diamonds$clarity[i] == 'SI2') 
      k <- k + 1
  }
  return(k)
}

countfreq(50)
2
countfreq(100) 
3
```

The first two rows of the dataframe are as below.

```
 carat  cut  color clarity  depth  table  price   x    y    z 
1 0.23 Ideal   E     SI2     61.5   55.0   326  3.95 3.98  2.43
2 0.21 Premium E     SI1     59.8   61.0   326  3.89 3.84  2.31
```

Comment: Pls mark homework as such next time (right after brushing up on data frame indexing, vectorization and vectorized logical operations). `nrow(diamonds[diamonds$color == 'E' & diamonds$clarity == 'SI2',])`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited above to clarify that I would like to keep the function (so that I can easily change the "n" without defining new dataframes each time) but lose the for loop.

Comment: You should really take the _"brushing up on data frame indexing, vectorization and vectorized logical operations"_ to heart. The tidyverse answer you accepted is overkill, slower and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to give you something that will answer your question and also help you understand a more general approach to answering questions like this using the `dplyr` package'

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>% # take the diamonds data.fram and group it
    group_by(color, clarity) %>% # 56 groups
    summarize(count = n()) %>% # add a count column
    filter(color=="E", clarity=="SI2") %>%  # filter the row you want
    .$count # just the single value as a result
```

`[1] 1713`

Note that can run any portion of the code to see the intermediate results. For example, to see the table of groups and the count for each, run just this part:

```
diamonds %>% # take the diamonds data.fram and group it
        group_by(color, clarity) %>% # 56 groups
        summarize(count = n())

# A tibble: 56 x 3
# Groups:   color [?]
   color clarity count
   <ord>   <ord> <int>
 1     D      I1    42
 2     D     SI2  1370
 3     D     SI1  2083
 4     D     VS2  1697
 5     D     VS1   705
 6     D    VVS2   553
 7     D    VVS1   252
 8     D      IF    73
 9     E      I1   102
10     E     SI2  1713
# ... with 46 more rows
```

Comment: Saw that you accepted the answer, but then I made a small grammar edit and noticed that the green checkbox disappeared. You can accept it again if you like. Let me know if you have any questions about how this works.